# PhoneGap/Cordova emulator for browser debugging

Tags: cordova

All,

Is there a PhoneGap/Cordova emulator/mock library so that we can develop and debug our app in a normal web browser (specially since the vast majority of our code is application logic with very few Cordova API calls here and there). Debugging/Coding through an actual mobile device or device emulator is a lot more cumbersome and disruptive of development workflow. Note that we don't want to test whether Cordova API works or not. We simply want to be able to run our app in a web browser w/o it dying because `navigator.suchAndASuch.thisAndThat()` is undefined.

TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [Ripple Emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com/).

Comment: does this work with the latest release of cordova? I am getting JSONP errors... but the code runs fine on device

Comment: Yes it works with latests Cordova versions. If you used the phonegap hosted version it should be up to date, if you want to use it locally install the NPM package: `npm install -g ripple-emulator`

Comment: To run emulation : `ripple emulate`

Comment: thanks @Fedir and sgimeno. I am a firefox user, and this works in firefox :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Cordova Browser, available with the newly released Cordova 4.0

Read the "**New Platform: Cordova Browser**" section on this page: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html